# How can I apply a user defined function to every column of a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, apply

I am trying to use the `count()` function from the `dplyr` package on every column of my data frame to count the number of each value per column in my df.

I tried  :

```
apply(df, 2, function(x){count_(df,X[1])})
```

However, it does not work. If I do

```
apply(df, 2, function(x){count_(df,"one of my column's name")})
```

it only applies it to that column.

How can I apply it to every column in my data frame ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please include data and/or code that will provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: `x` is not the same as `X`. And don't refer to df inside the function. That's what is causing you grief. The `x` is the column of interest. Just `count_` or `count` it.

Comment: `apply(df, 2, ...)` is very wrong for `data.frame`'s. Use `lapply`.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
apply(df, 2, table)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think table would work since it fails when used without apply.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a lot of elegant ways to do this, but try this:

```
zz=apply( iris  , 2 , function(x) { table(x) })
```

zz will be a list of occurrence counts, one list item for each column.  You could merge it all together if you want from there.

Edit: I just noticed someone above did the same with just "`table`" instead of the function definition.  Both will work, I always use a function since I end up messing around with it a bit.